# double byte character which one of it's bytes is an '<' or '>'

Tags: character-encoding

is there in any double byte encoding a character that one of it's bytes has the same value of the ASCII characters '<' or '>' ?
i cant seems to find one, but i have to make sure that there is no such cases, since such double byte characters might cause errors on html parsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *any* encoding? Almost certainly yes. In fact, there are hundreds of characters that have 0x3c or 0x3e (the values of `<` and `>` in ASCII) as one of the bytes of their UTF-16 encodings, for instance "☼", the UTF-16le representation of which looks like the ASCII for `<&`.

But it's not appropriate to deliver HTML in some random character set without also specifying out-of-band (for instance via HTTP headers) what encoding it's using, and possibly using other signals such as a BOM (which is required for HTML5) or an XML encoding specifier (which is required for XHTML in some cases as dictated by the XML standard).

And if your encoding is specified properly then there should be no problem, because the *characters* `<` and `>` are special in HTML, not the *bytes* 0x3c and 0x3e. Any "parser" that thinks differently is broken.

Comment: well, i do mean in any encoding, but, the character that has the 0X3c should be a valid character in some language. my question is if it is possible to see an html like this one:  "<b>some text ... some character that has 0X3e, but a valid character in some language </b>" in that case a parser might raise major problems